# Import 2 Angular projects in another javascript project

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, angular-elements

I have 2 separated Angular projects.
For each of them, I run the following CLI command:

`ng build --prod --output-hashing=none`

It creates the following files for each project:

`runtime.js
polyfills.js
main.js`

Now I want to import the projects into another project, which is a simple javascript project (not Angular project).

I know that the order is important and that `runtime.js` and `polyfills.js` appear twice.
So I made sure that these files are the same (because I use the same Angular version in both projects).

The imports in the simple javascript project look something like this:

```
<script src="runtime.js"></script>
<script src="polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="main1.js"></script>
<script src="main2.js"></script>
```

Unfortunately, only one of the projects seems to work this way (and there are no exceptions).
If I'll import only `main1.js` or only `main2.js` they will work properly.

I guess the problem is the dependency libraries I use in each project, that maybe override each other, but I don't know what I can do about it.

UPDATE:

Not sure if it's relevant, but in each Angular project, I use `@angular/elements` in order to publish the components I need. something like this:

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    const elem = createCustomElement(MyFirstComponent, { injector });
    customElements.define('my-first-element', elem);
  }
  ngDoBootstrap() {}
}
```

Then in the javascript project, I use it like this:

```
var elem1 = document.createElement('my-first-element');
container.append(elem1);
var elem2 = document.createElement('my-second-element');
container.append(elem2);
```

Comment: So do you have multiple app-roots?

Comment: Actually no. Please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `<app-root></app-root>` tag in your index.html.
You may need 2 different selector for your AppComponent:

```
// app.component.ts for the first project
selector: 'app-root-one',


// app.component.ts for the second project
selector: 'app-root-two',
```

Comment: Actually I don't use the app-root selectors. Please see the update of my question.